# Dynamic Agent Selection

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I currently am working on unifying multiple Jenkins file that all build the same software project, with the same steps, but handle different versions, ie 2.4 vs 3.5, the key difference between versions being the SDK, and subsequently VM/Jenkins agent it runs on.

What's the cleanest way to dynamically assign agent label, based on branch/tag of the code? I'm using a Declarative Pipeline and not found any example solutions, and not been able to come up with my own which either isn't very clean, or ends up using scripted, which we're trying to avoid.

Comment: Could you share us a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) ??

Answer (score 0):

This is a limitation of the declarative pipelines.

In scripted pipelines, you can easily supply an agent label to the `node(label)` step that is "computed", i.e. read from a file, based on a loop for versions to be built in code etc.